# How to validate credit card number without account creation in Braintree Gateway?

Tags: php, validation, braintree

I want to validate a credit card number in braintree without creating customer account. If the card valid means then only i will do some logic.

I have 3 step registration. In that first step i have to validate card details. 3rd step only i will save all the necessary details.

Comment: If you're storing credit card details in your step 3, then I hope that you're fully PCI compliant

Comment: What level of card validation do you need? Simply checking that the card number isn't random digits? Use the Luhn formula

Comment: @Mark Baker : for some credit card i check whether it is 12 or 16 digit number. But during create braintree credit account it shows invalid card details. i want to validate without create braintree credit account.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions or are looking for more help with your integration, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Consider using Braintree's [Drop-in Payment UI](https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/drop-in), which will do a client side validation of the credit card.

Otherwise, you have to [create or update a credit card, directly or indirectly, in order to run a card verification](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/card_verifications/overview):

```
result = Braintree::Customer.create(
  :first_name => "Fred",
  :last_name => "Jones",
  :credit_card => {
    :cardholder_name => "Fred Jones",
    :number => "4111111111111111",
    :cvv => "123",
    :expiration_date => "05/2020",
    :options => {
      :verify_card => true
    }
  }
)
```